# Office 365/EWS Updating an Organizer's Event from an Attendee Event

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365api

I'm currently using a combination of the Office365 REST APIs and EWS SOAP APIs to create/fetch/edit calendar events in my application. I've been using impersonation to act on behalf of an event's organizer and attendees.

**When updating a meeting I'm not sure of the best correlation between an organizer's meeting ItemId and an attendee's meeting ItemId.**

For example:

-> The app impersonates user A and creates an event on their calendar with a room resource(attendee) set as the meeting location.

-> One event and a copy of the event is now created on user A's calendar and the room's calendar. Each has a different ItemId.

Is there any way to retrieve the room meeting ID via the user's meeting ID or vice versa?

The best bet I found was using one of the extended MAPI properties of the EWS meeting called `CleanGlobalObjectID` that would supposedly be shared between the two items. This method would require multiple FindItems/GetItem calls just to get the shared event so I'm not sure if it's the best route.

Refs:

- http://www.infinitec.de/post/2009/04/13/Searching-a-meeting-with-a-specific-UID-using-Exchange-Web-Services-2007.aspx
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/da37a678-dd90-4f17-b978-d2179c7c29d2/how-to-get-organizer-itemid-from-attendees-calendar-item?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment
- [Get the organizer's calendar appointment using EWS for Exchange 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829039/get-the-organizers-calendar-appointment-using-ews-for-exchange-2010)

Comment: Can you define what you mean by Meeting ID are you talking about the EWSid of the appointment in the Meeting Room Mailbox is so no you will need to search for the appointment based on the CleanGlobalObjectID

Comment: Yeah I'm referring to the `ItemId` attribute within the `CalendarItem` of the Meeting Room's Calendar Mailbox.